# relative height for thumbnails in Laravel File Manager/Unisharp

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filesystem, unisharp-file-manager

I'm using unisharp file manager and I have a problem:
my Image files are in different dimensions, some are square, some other are rectangular.
I want to save thumbnails with original dimensions but the lfm config uses a static width and height size choice for thumbs:

```
    'thumb_img_width'          => 200, // px

    'thumb_img_height'         => 200, // px
```

what should I do?